# Is it safe to delete duplicate environment variables in the path system variable?

Tags: windows-10, environment-variables

There are multiple "C:\WINDOWS" environment variables and other various duplicated environment variables in the system environment variables that I want to delete because my environment variable is too large.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove duplicate paths in the PATH environment variable by a Powershell script. Before that, you should export the environment variables. Go to `regedit` and follow the path and export values:  [*Source*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559816/how-to-export-and-import-environment-variables-in-windows)

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment  

HKCU\Environment
```

Next, try this Powershell script:

```powershell
$RegKey = ([Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::LocalMachine).OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment", $True) 

$PathValue = $RegKey.GetValue("Path", $Null, "DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames") 

Write-host "Original path :" + $PathValue  

$PathValues = $PathValue.Split(";", [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) 

$IsDuplicate = $False 

$NewValues = @() 



ForEach ($Value in $PathValues) 

{ 

    if ($NewValues -notcontains $Value) 

    { 

        $NewValues += $Value 

    } 

    else 

    { 

        $IsDuplicate = $True 

    } 

} 



if ($IsDuplicate) 

{ 

    $NewValue = $NewValues -join ";" 

    $RegKey.SetValue("Path", $NewValue, [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::ExpandString) 

    Write-Host "Duplicate PATH entry found and new PATH built removing all duplicates. New Path :" + $NewValue 

} 

else 

{ 

    Write-Host "No Duplicate PATH entries found. The PATH will remain the same." 

} 



$RegKey.Close()
```

Be careful and check [this link](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-check-for-duplicate-5d9dd711) out to find the compatibility.